# Show site title without link

Tags: master-page

Is it possible to modify the v4.master on SP2010 so that the site title displays without a link? Here's the element from the master page:

```
<td class="s4-titletext">
  <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
      <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" 
         id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" 
         runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </h1>
  ....
</td>
```

In other words, can the title be displayed as an `<asp:Label>` or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out: Just need to remove the `SPLinkButton` and it works like a charm.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your question and the answer. Maybe you can post it as answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
<td class="s4-titletext">
  <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" 
         runat="server" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </h1>
  ....
</td>
```